# SQL XML, is there a technique by which I can get some columns in xml format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I want to store data from multiple tables into one table

```
table A (
p, q,
PRIMARY KEY (p,q)
)

table B (
p, m, n,
PRIMARY KEY (p,m,n)
)

table output(
p,
xml
)
```

The output should be like

for table A

```
 -------------------------------
|    p      |        xml        |
---------------------------------
|value of p | <q>some value</q> |
 -------------------------------
```

for table B

```
 -----------------------------------------------
|    p      |        xml                        |
------------------------------------------------
|value of p | <m>some value</m><n>some data</n> |
 -----------------------------------------------
```

This can be achieved by this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM Students s
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT 
        (
            SELECT * 
            FROM Students t
            WHERE t.DisplayName = s.DisplayName
            FOR XML RAW
        ) x1
)x
```

But I want to make the SQL generic enough so that given any table name we can get the above output.

The problem with the inner join is that then the query will not be generic

Comment: @marc_s Added the code in the description itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the result you want from one table you could use something like this:

```
select T.Table1ID,
       (
         select T.*
         for xml raw, type
       ) as x1
from Table1 as T
```

To apply the same pattern to another table you need to change the table name and the field name of the key column.

```
select T.Table2ID,
       (
         select T.*
         for xml raw, type
       ) as x1
from Table2 as T
```

If you want a even more generic version you can use dynamic SQL and build your query from a table name and a column name.

```
declare @TableName sysname 
declare @KeyColumnName sysname

set @TableName = 'master..spt_values'
set @KeyColumnName = 'Number'

declare @SQL nvarchar(500)

set @SQL = '
select '+@KeyColumnName+',
       (
         select T.*
         for xml raw, type
       ) as x1
from '+@TableName+' as T'

exec (@SQL)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted, it works generically on any table

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if I have misunderstood, but is this more or less the principle you are after?

```
;WITH Base AS
(
    SELECT   Cat    = PC.Name
            ,SubCat = SC.Name
    FROM Production.ProductCategory     PC
    JOIN Production.ProductSubcategory  SC  ON SC.ProductCategoryID = PC.ProductCategoryID
)
SELECT Cat, (SELECT SubCat FROM Base T2 WHERE T2.Cat = T1.Cat FOR XML AUTO )DT
FROM Base T1
```

Comment: This will work fine, but I want to avoid the inner join, the only problem is that I want to make the sql generic enough to work on any table with only p as the common column but this self join will impossible generically

Comment: I'm not sure how you could get sensible data returned without the `JOIN`. Maybe I don't understand. Please edit your post to make it more clear.